# update DB with onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

i try to update the status of a messae in my pm's by only clicking the read button on my page. so i found some solution here on this site, but it doesn't really work for me.

i use this ajax before the html button:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
function setRead(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_pm_status.php",
        data: { name: $("select[name='gelesen']").val()},
        success:function( msg ) {
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
       });
  }
</script>
```

the button is styled css and uses it's own javascript to toggle the content (open/close)
so i want to update the status by opening the message

```
<span class="toggleOpen" onclick="setRead()"><input type="hidden" method="post" name="gelesen" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">lesen</span>
```

the included site is

```
<?php
ini_set('include_path', 'inc');
    require("connect.php"); 

        {
                  $id = $_POST['id'];


            $sql = "UPDATE
                    PMS
                    SET
                    gelesen = 'yes'
                    WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' AND gelesen = 'no'";
                    mysql_query($sql) OR die("<pre>\n".$sql."</pre>\n".mysql_error());

        }
```

but i get always the notice of the undefined variable 'id'.
how can i give this variable to the included site?

---

because i have to wait 8 hours before i can reply i edit my post:

thanks for the answer but i still get the message of a undefined index: name
so the variable is not postet to my update_pm_staus.php
ihave updated my script to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

function setRead(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_pm_status.php",
        data: { id: $(this).children("[name='gelesen']").val()},
        success:function( msg ) {
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
       });
  }

and the update_pm_status.php to this:

```
    ini_set('include_path', 'inc');
    require("connect.php"); 

            $id = $_POST['name'];

            $sql = "UPDATE
                    PMS
                    SET
                    gelesen = 'yes'
                    WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' AND gelesen = 'no'";
                    mysql_query($sql) OR die("<pre>\n".$sql."</pre>\n".mysql_error());
```

i also changed my html like this in hope to bring it to work.

```
<span class="toggleOpen" onclick="setRead()" input type="hidden" method="post" name="gelesen" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">lesen</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are sending the `id` correctly, but you are sending it as `name`. You'd want to update your JavaScript to pass the key:value pair that you're expecting, with the key name that you expect in your PHP.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function setRead(){
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_pm_status.php",
            data: { id: $(this).children("[name='gelesen']").val()},
            success:function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            }
          });
        }
     </script>
```

You'll notice that in the `data: {}` block of the AJAX request, I've updated your key:value pair to be named `id`, rather than `name`. If you do what your key to be named `name` when POST'ing, then you'd want to update your PHP to look for that:

```
$id = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: Sorry I upvoted but then realised there is no `select`? Update it to `data: { id: $(this).children("[name='gelesen']").val()},` as this may be called from several `read` buttons

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late response. i got the to work. i use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setRead($id){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update_pm_status.php",
    data: { id: $id}
   });  }
```

and the html like this

```
onclick="setRead(this.id);
```

thanks for to all helping me out :)